# How to migrate from MySQL database to PostgreSQL if having a bit column?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Since the last days, i have been trying to migrate a MySQL database to PotsgreSQL, but there is a problem that doesn't let me succed: A bit column.

I have tried different methods: First i tried to use pgloader, because it seemed as the easiest, but i don't know how to write a script for this, so i took an example from internet:

```
load database
     from      mysql://dbu1:password@localhost/openbill
     into postgresql://dbu1:password2@localhost/openbill

 WITH include drop, create tables, no truncate,
      create indexes, reset sequences, foreign keys

  SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB', work_mem to '12MB', search_path to 'openbill'

 CAST type datetime to timestamptz
                drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null,
      type date drop not null drop default using zero-dates-to-null

 -- Create the database in postgresql to import into. If your db already exist this can be skipped
 BEFORE LOAD DO
 $$ create schema if not exists openbill; $$

;
```

The problem with this, is the last line, i didn't know how to change the openbill, and gave me errors, so i tried deleting it, but of course, because of that it doesn't created the tables for the import.

After a lot of headaches, i tried using a dump, for that, i readed that it was necesary to change the sintaxis to be compatible with postgresql, so i found this code that do that: https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter but for some reason, it fails when it gets to the first table with a bit column, to be more exact, not when creating it, but when inserting data, because for some reason, the bit seemed like  on the sql, and it gave me the error

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

I generated tha dump with:

```
mysqldump -h ip -u root -p --compatible=postgresql --default-character-set=utf8 database > database.sql
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Or if there is a better way to make this migration?

Comment: This might be a better question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should translate MySQL's `bit` type to PostgreSQL's `bit varying` type.

When selecting `bit` values in MySQL, they are displayed as strings (!) by default, which probably causes the error message you see:

```
root@lau56> SELECT id, val FROM bittest;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 | ▒   |
|  2 |  ▒   |
+----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can use the `bin` function to display them in binary notation:

```
root@lau56> SELECT id, bin(val) FROM bittest;
+----+------------+
| id | bin(val)   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 1111111111 |
|  2 | 10101010   |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will produce valid input for PostgreSQL's `bit varying` data type.

Comment: How would you make this while requesting a dump?

Comment: Don't really know... There's the [`--hex-blob`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) option in `mysqldump` that will dump the fields in hexadecimal. But that's not a format that PostgreSQL will accept. Perhaps you'll have to use mysql_fdw (don't know if it handles `bit` well), or you'll have to write something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some help, i found how to solve this. The main problem was what @Laurenz said, it returned strings instead of the bits, so i used the --hex-blob option and it generated the dump with these fields in hex format 0x00 instead of the strings. This helped because instead of seeing a lot of squares, i was able to see the hexs, so i used sublime text, selected all the 0x00, and changed it for their respective B'0', then it worked without problems.

This was my dump string at the end:

```
mysqldump -h ip -u root -p --compatible=postgresql --hex-blob --default-character-set=utf8 database > database.sql
```